# RemoteControlClient keeps on showing after service is closed

Tags: android, lockscreen

RemoteControlClient keeps on showing after service is closed 
I have implemented the RemoteControlClient  and it works correctly , I have been trying to search way to close the RemoteControlClient  after my app and service are closed I am unable to find any solution.Once i close my app or service it still keeps on showing the RemoteControlClient   on the lockscreen.

I have close my activity using `finish()`

and

my service using `stopSelf()`

```
here is the code for starting the RemoteControlClient 

    ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    MyRemoteControlEventReceiver.class.getName());

            AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            myAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
            // build the PendingIntent for the remote control client

            Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
            mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(myEventReceiver);
            PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
            // create and register the remote control client
             myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(
                    mediaPendingIntent);

            myRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
            |RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS
            | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT);
            myAudioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);

            myRemoteControlClient
                    .editMetadata(true)
                    .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "title")
                        .apply();
            myRemoteControlClient
                    .setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
            // Request audio focus for playback
            int result = myAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

My question is how to close the RemoteControlClient  after my app is closed or revice is closed

Is there any method that needs to be called as we do for service and activity.

Comment: Did you take in account that registerXXX methods usually have their opposite methods?

Comment: trying to search on same lines

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution? I have the same problem... Thx

Comment: unregister your remote control client